# "Not all constituents are callable" inside a loop

Tags: typescript

Imagine an array of items which can be a string, or a function that returns a string:

```
const arr: (string | (() => string))[] = [/* ... */]
```

TypeScript is happy with the following ternary expression testing the type of an array item and then returning the item or the result of calling the item:

```
// This works
const value = typeof arr[0] === 'string' ? arr[0] : arr[0]()
```

However, when indexing the array using a variable inside a loop, TypeScript complains that "Not all constituents of type 'string | (() => string)' are callable."

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // This fails: "not all constituents are callable"
    const value = typeof arr[i] === 'string' ? arr[i] : arr[i]()
}
```

But assigning the array item to a variable first succeeds:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const item = arr[i]

    // This works
    const value = typeof item === 'string' ? item : item()
}
```

My question is *why* this happens. I suspect it's because the variable could change between testing the type and calling the function. But even when assigned as `const`, which prevents reassignment, it still fails in the same way:

```
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    const j = i

    // This still fails
    const value = typeof arr[j] === 'string' ? arr[j] : arr[j]()
}
```

How does TypeScript process this?

Comment: What if you change `i` before using `arr[i]`? Then the narrowed type is not correct.

Comment: Same error: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQLhgCmgglmA5jAH3TQEoYBeAPhkx1xJIG0BdCmFgKC4DMQF0ANgFNYWNgAYA3DDEAeeEgB0wvFAAW0rAGotZAN4cYRmRMPHQkWADc4AgK5CATGygBPAA5CQ3BQkZZWciCYAHJaPBCYAH5ff1ZURD8A0g4AXyA

Comment: No, I mean [this](https://tsplay.dev/wj1oMW). It's easier to illustrate with if-else, but anyways, here I'm changing `i` before using it. That would mean the inference would no longer be correct.

Comment: TypeScript doesn't really remember what the types of things are if they are an indexed access like `arr[i]` or `obj[key]`. That's why you have to put them into a variable first. This *might* not be how the compiler actually works, but it's what I've always thought.

Comment: Thanks, @caTS that makes sense. What about the last case though, doing `const j = i` and then using `j` to index the arrays. That couldn't be reassigned between type check and usage, right?

Comment: Well, lemme reword the last comment I sent. Any time you have an *expression* that is used to index into something, it is not inferred or remembered. Since variable usage is an expression, this applies. Other expressions include `j + 1`, `"thing" + j`, etc. That's why you have to store the indexed access into a variable - so that the value is being checked and narrowed, not the expression `arr[i]`.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks! If you want to turn this into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Actually, I think jcalz has covered this already in one of their always exemplary answers which actually explains how the compiler works with this... I'll try to find it first before trying to write an answer...

Comment: Much to my disappointment, I could not find it... So I tried to get a little deeper with my thought process. Anyways, I've learned two things: always save jcalz's answers, and now that I have given some thought to this, I also understand a little more about this problem :)

Comment: Awesome answer; thanks for putting the thought into this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler does not narrow a type if it's not a simple expression. Let's take this as the example:

```
const value = typeof arr[i] === 'string' ? arr[i] : arr[i]()
```

`arr[i]` - This might seem simple, but actually, `i` is only known at runtime. That means the compiler doesn't know what `i` is; all it knows is that `i` is a number. Compare this to:

`arr[0]` - This is known at compile-time. The key `0` is constant (as it is hard coded) and the compiler can infer that the key `0` of this object is narrowed here:

```
const value = typeof arr[0] === 'string' ? arr[0] : arr[0]()
//                                         ~~~~~~
```

And actually, if you narrow `i` to a literal like `0`, you can then use it as if it were `0`:

```
if (i === 0) {
    const value = typeof arr[i] === 'string' ? arr[i] : arr[i](); // OK
}
```

That's also why if you put `arr[i]` in a variable before using it, you can now narrow it...

```
const thing = arr[i];
```

`thing` - It's become a simple expression that can't be reduced any further. The compiler knows that this value is a `string` or `() => string`, and when you narrow it, it's able to determine that it's now a `string`:

```
const value = typeof thing === "string" ? thing : thing();
//                                        ~~~~~
```

In other words, individual variables can be narrowed, but not more complex expressions that rely on other variables. That's simplifying it a bit but that is how it works, in essence.